# How can I create a Validation rule for this scenario

Tags: visualforce, trigger, picklist, validation, validation-rule

When I selected a picklist value on the Lead object and Lead converted into an Account. Now the value of picklist should not be editable.
For this, I have to write a validation rule.

Comment: Picklist where, on the lead? It is read only once converted unless you gave user the magic keys (permissions)

Comment: nope, it is on the account object when the lead is converted to account the value of picklist should not editable.

Comment: Which picklist field you are questioning about. This question is some what unclear.

Answer (score 1):

When you convert a lead, Sales-force creates a new account, contact, and, optionally, an opportunity using the information from the lead. Any campaign members are moved to the new contact and the lead becomes read only.

All open and closed activities from the lead are attached to the account, contact, and opportunity. You can assign the owner of the records, and schedule a follow-up task. When you assign a new owner, only the open activities are assigned to the new owner. If you have custom lead fields, that information can be inserted into custom account, contact, or opportunity fields. Converted leads can't be viewed, although they appear in lead reports. Salesforce updates the Last Modified Date and Last Modified By system fields on converted leads when picklist values included on converted leads are changed.